# reactjs improving my code for calling childNode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to improve my function. currently this is how I access my childNodes

```
const handleClick = (data) => {
    console.log(
      "canvas before ",
      data.currentTarget.children[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].style.height
    );
    console.log("wrapper ", data.currentTarget.style.height);

    // make my echart dimension same as my wrapper dimension
    data.currentTarget.children[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].style.height =
      data.currentTarget.style.height;
    data.currentTarget.children[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].style.width =
      data.currentTarget.style.width;
  };
```

and this is where I am calling my handleClick

```
  return (
    <ResponsiveGridLayout layouts={layout}>
      <div key="1" onClick={handleClick}>
        <NewvsReturnVisitors />
        <span className="remove" style={removeStyle}>
          x
        </span>
      </div>
    </ResponsiveGridLayout>
  );
```

I feel that handleClick function can be further improve, will appreciate if anyone can give me advice on how to improve my handleClick function, making it more readable and more optimize if its possible.

Click this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-with-resizable-forked-ub5v2?file=/src/index.js:1228-1483) for my codesandbox

Comment: manipulating DOM in react is generally not recommended

Comment: then how should i go about achieving the same end goal without manipulating DOM?

Comment: In react, a child can communicate with the parent through callbacks and the parent communicates with the child through props. What you are doing is very hacky and prone to error. If passing a prop is not possible, you may want to consider using ref in this case. See https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Answer (score 0):

So I went and discard the function that manipulate the DOM and use more library directly inside my chart object.

newvsreturnvistors.js

```
import * as echarts from "echarts";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import useComponentSize from "@rehooks/component-size";

const Newvsresturnvisitors = () => {
  
  ...

  const chart = useRef(null);
  let chartInstance = null;
  const size = useComponentSize(chart);

  function renderChart() {
    const renderInstance = echarts.getInstanceByDom(chart.current);

    if (renderInstance) {
      chartInstance = renderInstance;
    } else {
      chartInstance = echarts.init(chart.current);
    }
    chartInstance.setOption(option);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    renderChart();
    if (chartInstance != null) {
      chartInstance.resize({
        height: size.height
      });
    }
  }, [size]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={chart}
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        background: "white"
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

I import component size to read the current chart dimension. Then in  my useEffect, I check for size changes and call the resize function to adjust my chart size accordingly.

working link is the same in my question. If there is a even better way to do this, please feel free to comment, I want to improve too.